# Delete selected/all rows from gridview with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

As the title says, I have a simple 5column/5rows GridView which represents a shopping cart in asp.net. I need to use javascript to delete selected row and all the rows on button click. How could that be done? Total price should change too when an item is removed. Thx in advance.

This is sample aspx code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Kosarica.aspx.cs" Inherits="Spletna_kosarica_2.Kosarica" EnableSessionState="True" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <h2>Kosarica:</h2>
        <p>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="440px" 
                AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
            </asp:GridView>
        </p></div>
    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" 
        Text="Dodaj artikel" Width="143px" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Total price:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to post some code before we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a web service to communicate with the server + ajax. Javascript can't do this alone, because it runs in a client browser.

There are numerous guides, documentations, tutorials etc, that explain this matter deeper. There are multiple ways of doing this, you just have to pick what's best for your situation and skill.

Here is a video tutorial about web services in asp.net http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet

Comment: Can you provide any useful link, that explains this on a simple matter? I googled some and there are only big codes, that i don't understand yet.

Comment: @cvenko, updated. If it isn't enough, simply use Google, I bet you can find thousands of records just by typing simple: `asp.net webservice`